# Error while installing Flask and Paho mqtt for Pi-Strech

Tags: pi

For Pi- ESP8266 mqtt communication, I tried to install Flask and Paho for RPi but I am getting this error when I type  `sudo apt-get upgrade`

[image: error]

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Please post the actual text of errors not a screen shot as they are totally unsearchable and hard to read

Comment: I started again by reconnecting with putty and the issue does not arise.